# JQuery Smooth Scroll - How to not target one anchor link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the following Jquery to smooth scroll between the anchor links on my page. I have one link that I would like this not to target - is there a way to edit the code to target all but one anchor link?

I have copied the link below also.

```
var $root = $('html, body');

$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
  }, 500);
});
```

This is the link I do not want to be called:

```
<a href="#" class="cn-set-cookie button wp-default">Ok</a>
```

These are links I do want to call with the function:

```
<li class="key-details"><a href="#key-details-scroll">Key Information</a></li>
<li class="about"><a href="#about">About the Service</a></li>
<li class="health"><a href="#health-experience">Health Experience</a></li>
```

Comment: Change `href` to something else like `javascript:void(0);` or add a class to it and avoid call function for that specific class. If you put all your anchors that bind smooth scroll on them in your question above, i can fix that.

Comment: Hi Colin. Sounds helpful thank you - I've updated the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution** 1:

```
var $root = $('html, body');

$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if($(this).hasClass('wp-default')) return;// with this line of code you'll prevent to call function on "OK" anchor
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

**Solution** 2:
Or you can modify your code in this way:

```
var $root = $('html, body');

$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]:not(".wp-default")', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

**Solution** 3:
Another approach is using other properties for `href`:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cn-set-cookie button wp-default">Ok</a>
```

`javascript:void(0);` will prevent any js function to be called by this anchor.

**P.S**: You can use this class name as well `cn-set-cookie` instead of `wp-default` or set a class to those anchors that you don't want to smooth scroll called by them.

Comment: There is probably some other anchor having the class `wp-default` and `href="#"`... Which has to be smooth scrolled. Better use a specific class.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette ofc, as i mentioned in comments too. But this what OP provided as HTML content, and will gave OP a nice clue with 3 options ahead.

Comment: Well... 2 solutions out of 3 are error prone and will certainly lead to another question. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette +1 for your comment and a P.S for OP.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a class... Say "no_smooth".

```
<a href="#" class="cn-set-cookie button wp-default no_smooth">Ok</a>
```

Then exclude it using [`:not()`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp).

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]:not(".no_smooth")', function (event) {
  //... Rest unchanged
});
```

Comment: `.not` is `jquery` function and has differnces with `:not()`. `:not()` is css selector. Edit please

Comment: Well seen. Thanks.

Comment: That is just what I was looking for. Thank you both.